# htlatex inserting environment in verbatim

Tags: spacing, verbatim, code, htlatex

I want to get htlatex to put some text into my HTML file verbatim. The problem
is that it keeps redo-ing my spacing. So, for example, I use a cf.cfg like this.

```
\Preamble{html}
\ConfigureEnv{tawny}
{\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<pre><code class="clojure">}\EndNoFonts}
{\NoFonts \HCode{</code></pre>}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

And a document like this...

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{tawny}%
{}%
{}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tawny}
(defclass Pizza
  :super Thing)
\end{tawny}
\end{document}
```

which produces this piece of html (and the rest!)

```
<pre><code class="clojure"> (defclass Pizza :super Thing)
</code></pre>
```

while what I want is:

```
<pre><code class="clojure"> 
(defclass Pizza 
   :super Thing)
</code></pre>
```

with indentation and spacing preserved

So, the pre tag has been defeated because htlatex has re-ordered things.
I tried using alltt -- so redefinign tawny in the example above.

```
\newenvironment{tawny}%
{\begin{alltt}}%
{\end{alltt}}%
```

And htlatex puts in nbsp and br tags which don't really make sense in a
pre tag.

```
<pre><code class="clojure"><div class="alltt">
<!--l. 11--><p class="noindent" ><div class="obeylines-v">
(defclass&#x00A0;Pizza
<br />&#x00A0;&#x00A0;:super&#x00A0;Thing)
</div>
</div>
</code></pre>
```

I've tried the documentation, and looking through the source, but cannot see
where this behaviour comes from nor if it is configurable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\ScriptEnv` command to define verbatim environment:

```
\Preamble{html}
\ScriptEnv{tawny}
{\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<pre><code class="clojure">\Hnewline}\EndNoFonts}
{\NoFonts \HCode{</code></pre>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

resulting html:

```xml
<pre><code class="clojure"> 
(defclass Pizza
  :super Thing)
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Superb. This is just what I needed. Many thanks!