# htlatex/tex4ht with ScriptEnv and HTML entities

Tags: tex4ht, html, htlatex

I am using htlatex to translate from LaTeX to HTML. I've created a \ScriptEnv environment for code as suggested by this answer:

[htlatex inserting environment in verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204180/htlatex-inserting-environment-in-verbatim)

It's working well, but it is being rather too literate -- there is no conversion to HTML entities, so any code with "<"'s is being handled badly.

Is there any way to stop this?

Edited:

In my case, the situation is worse because some of my output looks like an HTML tag with open and close <>.

```
(isubclasses OntologyBook)
;;=> #{#<OWLClassImpl <bc33d2c3-7ecb413c-bb04-83af2295c465#walk_through#TakeWing>>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another edit:

of you don't want to postprocess html, you may use different mean to achieve verbatim environment. For example with `fancyvrb` package:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\def\StartSuppressPage{\nobreak\vfil\penalty0\vfilneg\vtop\bgroup}
\def\EndSuppressPage{\egroup}
\renewenvironment{tawny}
{\IgnorePar\EndP\StartSuppressPage\HCode{<pre><code class="clojure">}\HtmlParOff\NoFonts\Verbatim}
{\endVerbatim\EndSuppressPage\HCode{</code></pre>}\EndNoFonts\HtmlParOn\par}
\Configure{fancyvrb}{}{}{}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

and sample of resulting html:

```html
tudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae
tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta
vehicula.
</p>

   <pre><code class="clojure">
<a 
 id="x1-3r1"></a>(defclass&#x00A0;Pizza
<a 
 id="x1-5r2"></a>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;:super&#x00A0;Thing)
<a 
 id="x1-7r3"></a>tady&#x00A0;je&#x00A0;radek
<a 
 id="x1-9r4"></a>a&#x00A0;&#x003E;&#x00A0;b&#x00A0;&amp;&#x00A0;c
   </code></pre>
<!--l. 15--><p class="indent" >   Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis v
```

Edit:

it seems that in this case lua filter for `make4ht` must be used. Use this `.mk4` file:

```lua
local filter= require "make4ht-filter"
local entities = function(s)
  return '<code class="clojure">' .. s:gsub('<code class="clojure">(.-)</code>', function(a) 
    local escapes = {["<"]="lt",[">"]="gt",["&"]="amp"}
    return a:gsub("([%<%>%&])", function(x)
      return "&"..(escapes[x] or x) .. ";"
    end)
   end) .. '</code>'
end
local process = filter(entities, uj)
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex{} 
  Make:match("html$", process)
else
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:match("html$", process)
end
```

filter `entities` is defined, which process content of `<code class="clojure">` element and convert all `<`,`>` and `&` to html entities:

```
<pre><code class="clojure"> 
(defclass Pizza
  :super Thing)
  (isubclasses OntologyBook)
  ;;=&gt; #{#&lt;OWLClassImpl &lt;bc33d2c3-7ecb413c-bb04-83af2295c465#walk_through#TakeWing&gt;&gt;}
</code></pre>
```

---

Old version:

Content of `\ScriptEnv` is exported verbatim, without any processing, so it seems that this can't be solved at the LaTeX side. But you can post-process `html` with some tool to replace these prohibited characters with html entities. Some `Lua` script could be used for that, but easiest way is to use `tidy` command:

```
tidy  -m  -utf8 -q -i filename.html
```

before:

```xml
<pre><code class="clojure"> 
  a > b & c
</code></pre>
```

after

```xml
  <pre>
<code class="clojure"> 
  a &gt; b &amp; c
</code>
</pre>
```

with [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) you can automatize this. make build file `filename.mk4`:

```lua
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex{} 
else
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:htlatex{}
  Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")
end
```

with this build file, you will be able to quickly view your file with

```
make4ht -m draft -c yourconfigfile.cfg filename
```

and `tidy` will be used only for final build. Other feature is that all output `html` files will be processed (this is useful if you split sections or chapters to standalone html files)

Comment: Other environments do this escaping though, so can't understand why it's not possible with ScriptEnv. Unfortunately, the tidy solution doesn't work. I've modified the question with an explanation.

Comment: @PhilLord that's because \ScriptEnv is used for inclusion of javascript, for example and you don't want to escape html entities in javascript

Comment: Ah. Is there not a better environment which is "verbatim but with no fonts or spans, or indeed anything"?

Comment: @PhilLord I had some success with `fancyvrb` package, I wil edit my answer

Comment: Okay, so I have two options here. I've got a preprocessor step working also using Emacs. I shall think on which to use. Thanks for the help!